# Как пользоваться данными в плагине jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Допустим, классическая болванка jQuery-плагина:

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        property: 'value'
    },
    methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('myPlugin');
                if (typeof data === 'undefined') {
                    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                    $(this).data('myPlugin', {
                        target: $this,
                        settings: settings
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        destroy: function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('myPlugin');
                $this.removeData('myPlugin');
            })
        },    
        somethingDo: function () {
            // Здесь нужно извлечь данные
            var data = $(this).data('myPlugin');

            // Затем что-то сделать, в результате изменив data
            // ...

            // Затем положить данные обратно
            $(this).data('myPlugin', data);
        }
    };
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        $.error('Метод с именем ' + method + ' не существует для jQuery.myPlugin');
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Не совсем понимаю, если идет работа с данными, то мне в каждом методе плагина придется делать так:

```
        // Здесь нужно извлечь данные
        var data = $(this).data('myPlugin');

        // Затем что-то сделать, в результате изменив data
        // ...

        // Затем положить данные обратно
        $(this).data('myPlugin', data);
```

Неужели это единственный путь? Возможно есть другое решение? Ведь это же, считай повтор кода? Как правильно обращаться с данными плагина в его методах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882165/how-i-can-use-data-in-jquery-plugin